# npm install stuck in linux but not on windows

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install

Is there any difference between the way npm communicates for `npm install` on linux and windows?

I'm facing problem on a specific network, but only on linux systems. Windows works fine. I switched to windows and tried on same network, it worked fine.

Linux npm install works fine on other network.

I need to find something before i tell the network guy where exactly the problem is.

A 5 min `npm install` keeps going on for the whole day, and still doesnt complete!

So far I've tried with archlinux, ubuntu 14, 16

Comment: try installing as  npm install --verbose and see if logs returns something useful

Comment: Already tried, nothing. It just keeps waiting on `fetchMetadata` for most of the packages. Some get installed, for some it takes time... a LOT of time.

Comment: Try few things: `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`  , or  `npm cache clean` or, update nodejs and npm itself to latest stable verison.. Since log didn't provide any useful info, so i think trying one of the above combination won't be a bad idea.

Comment: naah, had tried that too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860219/npm-gets-stuck-on-fetchmetadata-network

Comment: happens me once.. The problem I face that time was low memory issue. After adding enough amount of swap space I was able to complete

Comment: well i have 4 gigs free and all 8 gigs of swap space free. also facing the issue on other linux machines. And the main point is, It works fine on other network

Comment: can always give a shot to `npm install` with `--no-optional`