# Truffle init failing

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm trying to run truffle in a linux virtual machine with a windows 10 host. When I run `truffle init` this is the error that I get...

```
DownloadingError: write EPROTO 140718189083520:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:827:

at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:880:14)
```

I'm not really sure what's causing the error or how to solve it. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with proxies.

I suggest you update your node environment to at least v10.16.0.

If that doesn't work try the answers to this other post.

[npm gets stuck on fetchMetadata -> network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860219/npm-gets-stuck-on-fetchmetadata-network)

Comment: Glad it was useful.